i want to deploy a djago project, using gitlab cicd. but i see "module not found error".but the path seems to be set correclty
I am currently working on a django project and need to deploy this to the server. I use gitlab for ci/cd purpose. for requests, i use the gunicorn and the nginx. i dockerized the nginx and the 'vardast' project and by using a docker-compose file i tried to build and deploy both and connect them on server. but this
error
occurs that says No module found No module named 'vardast'. this is the directory being dockerized of my project ->
dir
Note: wsgi.py is inside the 'vardast'
this is my docker-compose file,
version: '3.3'

services:
  vardast:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - no-cache=true
    container_name: vardast
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
      nproc: 65536
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"  # This ensures the app is accessible from outside the container
    # command: ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "vardast.wsgi:application"]

  nginx:
    # image: nginx:latest
    # container_name: nginx
    build:
     context: ./
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    # volumes:
    #   - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf  # Mount the nginx.conf file
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx
    depends_on:
      - vardast

# networks:
#   default:
#     driver: bridge


and this is the dockerfile I used for 'vardast'
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app/
RUN echo "Current working directory:" && pwd && ls -la
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    #python3 \
    #python3-pip \
    # && apt-get clean \
    # && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    # RUN pip install docker
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# RUN  apt-get install  python3 py3-pip
# RUN  pip install --upgrade docker 

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

# Define environment variable
# ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=vardast.settings
ENV ENCRYPTION_KEY=TncyNWJ____________________TDE2SU______0=


# Run the Gunicorn server
# CMD ["gunicorn", "--chdir", "/app", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "vardast.wsgi:application"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "vardast.wsgi:application"]

but still I dont understand why it doesnt find the 'vardast' module

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
